# Agda: Unable to do IO - missing Data.FFI, IO.FFI

Tags: io, functional-programming, agda

I've done stuff in agda as a hobby for a few months now, and I started to make a provably safe\correct Tic Tac Toe game.
I've got all the lemmas proofs and definitions, but now that I have tried to get input and print output I've ran into a problem.
All "Hello World" examples taken from the web have failed, most of them with the message that I am missing Data.FFI and IO.FFI.
I've looked around for a solution online,, but none were of use. One website said I should run "cabal install" from agda/agda-stdlib-0.11/ffi but I"m not even sure if I have that folder on my computer, and I have many folders named "agda", all over the computer (this is my first time using linux for something, so I probably did stuff horribly)
This is the error I get when trying to run the code from EMACS with agda-mode (C-c C-x C-c)

```
Compilation error:

MAlonzo/Code/Agda/Primitive.hs:4:18:
    Could not find module ‘Data.FFI’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

MAlonzo/Code/Agda/Primitive.hs:5:18:
    Could not find module ‘IO.FFI’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

If it matters, I'm running Ubuntu.
Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One website said I should run "cabal install" from agda/agda-stdlib-0.11/ffi

That is correct. From the [README](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/agda/agda-stdlib/v0.11/README.agda) for the standard library *0.11*:

```
-- To compile the library using the MAlonzo compiler you first need to
-- install some supporting Haskell code, for instance as follows:
--
--   cd ffi
--   cabal install
```

Comment: I see, thank you. But the problem is I can't find the "agda-stdlib-0.11" folder at all on my computer (I've searched all the files). I thought maybe I didn't download it correctly, and there's a link for a download in the Agda wiki, I don't understand how to download from the website they linked (launchpad.net).

Comment: [Here](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Libraries.StandardLibrary) you can download the standard library v0.11.

Comment: You can also search for the `README.agda` file in your computer.

Comment: How can you compile your project without pointing explicitly at the location of the standard library?